# Where to put "for free"

Tags: word-order

Which of the following sentences is more correct?

> Listen to Deep House and other electronic music on XXX **for free**.

> Listen to Deep House and other electronic music **for free** on XXX.

Comment: For that matter, even "Listen for free Deep House and other electronic music on XXX." should make as much sense as either of the two. *For free* is parenthetical here.

Comment: Do you want to put the emphasis on *for free* or *on XXX*?

Answer (score 1):

Which is the most important aspect: the XXX location where the music can be listened to, or the fact that the music can be listened to for free (or free of charge)? The most important of these two is usefully placed at the end of the sentence, in a position of emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it belongs to the end with a comma.

> Listen to Deep House and other electronic music on XXX, **for free**.

This way, you are specifying an additional attribute of the main object which is *music on XXX*.